# Configure simple message broker to use asa queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I'm using spring-boot.

I have to configure websocket message broker to use as a queue.
Is any way to use embedded simplemessagebroker in this mode?
When i define prefix '/queue' for message broker, it works as topic - all clients receive message.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends          
AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Value("${websocket.origin:}")
private String allowedOrigins;

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    if(allowedOrigins != null && !allowedOrigins.isEmpty()){
        registry.addEndpoint("/wsendpoint").setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins).withSockJS();
    }else{
        registry.addEndpoint("/wsendpoint").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

}

Thank you.